# Apex 18.1 How to create Multi Column LOV to Return multiple values in multiple columns separately

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

using Oracle Apex 18.1 and want to have multi-column LOV and return multiple values in columns separately like this will return Department_Id and Manager_Id values in my page items Department_Id and Manager_Id separately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not how Apex LoV works. It must have exactly two values: `display` and `return`. `Display` is what you see, `Return` is what is actually "stored" into the column. One column, not two (or more) of them.

That's unlike Oracle Forms, which lets you create a LoV that contains *many* columns and map those values to different form items.

So, what you could try is to use a "Set value" dynamic action and - once you fetch the return value into the item, populate other items on the page.

Comment: yes, this feature exist since (at least) Forms 6 (as per my knowledge) and oracle can give an alternate for developers came from oracle forms (may be as a plug-in), don't know. Actual problem is that our client has their customer's data and some has multiple accounts in same bank so they need to Select once both customer id and his account from an LOV for some kinds of transactions. There can also be some other scenarios like-wise.

Comment: Let's go back to Forms 3.0 (that's what I remember) :) If you're interested, have a look at the Skillbuilder's **Super LoV** plug-in (https://www.skillbuilders.com/free-oracle-apex-tutorials/skillbuilders-oracle-apex-plugin-super-lov-2-0/). I'm trying not to use plug-ins as they, sometimes, tend to stop working when Apex is upgraded to a higher version. Unless people (who wrote it) keep maintaining it, or you (person who uses it) are capable of doing it yourself, you might have certain problems.

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with this is either two LOVs that are parent child.

Set an LOV for departments, and have the second LOV with Managers which takes the department you have as a parameter.

Or I set it up like

```
SELECT department || ' ' || manager as d
     , manager as r
  FROM database
```

And then set up something to fill the department based on the manager chosen.

This assumes the manager is in only one department. I guess you might be able to populate a list with managers who are in multiple departments and then return the PK of the table, and use that return to save into your table.

Comment: is there any other way around to have this type of functionality using a modal dialog with IR or something else?

Comment: @Oralover I guess you could set the main page to be an IR and then from the dialog with the details, open up another modal dialogue where you select the values you want. But for me, I think it would be better to just have everything in one column. Set a popup LOV for selecting department and manager concacted, and then when saving you assign the values based on the return of that LOV(your return should be something unique, managers are probably unique) and then you assign the other value based on what you selected.

Comment: thanks for suggestion and guidance, will see what is possible in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://uthamaselvan.wordpress.com/2019/11/24/can-we-see-how-to-make-multiple-lov-in-oracle-apex-19-2/) might be what you are looking for. Otherwise you might have to [make your own](https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/demos/Input/ComboBox/Multi-column).